# If div id "arrow" exists, make its table row have class "odd0"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have an alternative table row color with the following javascript code:

```
function alternate(id){     
    if(document.getElementsByTagName){  
        var table = document.getElementById(id);   
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");    
        for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){           
            if(i % 2 ==0 ){ 
                rows[i].className = "odd0"; 
            }else { 
                rows[i].className = "even2"; 
            }
        }
    }
} // end function
```

What I would like to add in here, is to make the condition of either of the following:

- If Div id "arrow" exists in the table row, then make the classname "odd0"
- If Div id "arrow" exists in the table row, then make the classname the same color as the row above it.

My first attempt was to try to make the classname "odd0" if the div id "arrow" exists; however, it just breaks my code or doesn't read it.

I attempted the following, by either making it into its own function or inserting it within the for loop...

```
 if (document.getElementById("arrow")) {
  rows[i].className = "odd0";
 }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you really want jQuery solutions?  You seem to be using straight JavaScript here.  This *would* be rather easy with jQuery.

Comment: Can you throw up some example code of what your table looks like? I'm having a hard time envisioning an example.

Comment: Also, you can only have one div with id arrow in your whole document.  If you have more than one, you do not have valid HTML.  Instead you need an "arrow" class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague and your requirements seem contradictory.  But, *I think* what you want is for your rows to alternate between `odd0` and `even2`, unless you have an `arrow` in your row.  Then you want the current row to have the same class as the row above it.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Because you put jQuery as a tag, I will give you a jQuery answer.  If you don't know jQuery, I would recommend learning it.  It makes this kind of class/css manipulation **a lot** easier than straight JavaScript, and takes care of all of the cross-browser issues for you.

```
function alternate(id) {
    var i = 1;
    // Go through each row
    $('#'+id).find('tr').each(function() {
        // If this isn't an "arrow" row, increment the count
        if ($(this).find('.arrow').length < 1) {
            i++;
        }
        // Decide whether the row is odd or even
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            $(this).addClass('even2');
        } else {    
            $(this).addClass('odd0');
        }
    });
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/uBgYH/1/

Comment: Sorry for the vague description. I didn't mind which one was the solution, but javascript is something that I tend to use, but I have used jquery from time to time since there are a lot of quick fixes for it out there.  Thank you for the VERY fast answer!

Answer (score 2):

Just so that you know you should only be using one id that is set to 'arrow', assuming that is the case:

```
 var arrow = document.getElementById('arrow');
 var row = arrow.parent;
 row.setAttribute('class', 'odd0');
```

This code gets the parent of the arrow div and set's it's class to 'odd0'. With jQuery you could do this like:

```
 $('#arrow').parent().addClass('odd0');
```

If you have multiple divs with the ID: 'arrow', then you need to change them to have the class arrow instead, and the code would be something like:

```
 var arrows = document.getElementsByClassName('arrow');
 for(var i = 0; i < arrows.length; i++) {
     arrows.parent.setAttribute('class', 'odd0');
 }
```

Or again, with jQuery

```
 $('.arrow').parent().addClass('odd0');
```